# Laravel get documents that has x value in append attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Case Scenario Model User  that has append attribute called custom
this custom attribute might differ between one document to the other
for example

```
 public function getCustomAttribute()
    {  
         return  $this->id % 2;//this is an example to showcase that it will be different but it's not my case
    }
```

this will return 0 or 1 depending on if the id is even or odd
I want to get only users with the 1 value how can I achieve this in the query since I want to use pagination

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your questions correct you can try to do like that:

```
 protected $appends = ['custom'];

 public function getCustomAttribute(): int
    {  
         return (int) $this->attributes['id'] % 2;
    }
```

Comment: No,it's not this is already done my question how can I get users with this custom value 1 for example

Comment: when you call your model, you can use where('custom', 1)->get()

Comment: No you can't where is only for real db columns

Comment: Hmm in this case I think using a custom attribute is not so nice way, but if you want so much. You can get your model collection first and then use the where clause, for example, 

Your model::all()->where('custom', 1); I guess it works fine.

but you other options as well instead of mutators, use scopes or raw queries, which one would be more effective at this case I guess